# Notification Twitter user updated status or posted retweet?

Tags: api, twitter, notifications, analysis

I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612563/get-push-notification-from-twitter-on-status-updates , but there was no answer.

I'm looking to receive some sort of notification when one of my Twitter app users update their status or retweet. I realize I can ping there feed every couple minutes and figure out if they updated their statuses or retweeted, but this is not efficient ( and counts against their rate limit ) ... There must be a way to do this, because multiple analysis site like Klout exist, and they are able to track every tweet and retweet. If someone has insight on how to accomplish this, please let me know.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a question that will point anyone trying to figure this out in the right direction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101476/consume-a-streamreader-stream-net-from-a-web-request-as-it-streams). It explains and has links on how to accomplish this through the streaming api's for Twitter. [Twitter User Streams](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/user-streams/suggestions)